# Strategy for drawing a line at bottom of an html table cell to reflect a relative magnitude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I maintain a small webapp that has an AngularJS front-end.  It's used to monitor the status of results in a largish framework.  It displays a table of data, and uses cell colors to report other dimensions of information.

I'm trying to "pack more information" into it, so someone can understand what's going on in the system, and it's reasonable to assume that the person will be very familiar with the framework and the visual clues presented in the view.

Each cell shows data about the success/failure rate of a particular operation in a particular time period.  The color is used to indicate where on a scale that current rate is.

I'd like to find a way to show the "volume" of operation calls for each time period.  Each cell has a tooltip that shows the actual volume, but I'd like people to be able to see at a glance what the relative volume is of these operations.

So, I envisioned simply drawing a black line at the bottom of the data cell, from the left side to the right side, to reflect the relative volume of this operation in this time period, considering all the values in the column.  The cell with a line going all the way across the cell would be the cell with the largest volume of calls in that time period.  All the other cells in the column would have a line of relative length to that one.

So, in this HTML and AngularJS app, what are some elements and strategies I would need to do this?  I'm "familiar" with Javascript, at least enough to build this somewhat simple AngularJS app, although I'm mostly a Java developer.  I believe drawing lines in Javascript requires using a Canvas.  Is it even practical to draw lines on top of HTML tables?

**Update**:

The answer gave me all the tools I needed, but didn't directly address the question, so I'm just adding an update showing what I did.

I put the following in the top-level style block of the page:

```
    .cell-bar {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

I put the following at the end of the "td" definition:

```
<div class="cell-bar" ng-style="{'width': computeBarWidth(name, 5)}"></div>
```

In my angularjs module, I defined the following function:

```
    $scope.computeBarWidth  =
        function(name, interval) {
            if ($scope.maxMap[interval]) {
                return (Math.round($scope.getTotalCount(name, interval) / $scope.maxMap[interval] * 100)) + "%";
            }
        };
```

The "`$scope.maxMap`" hash was earlier computed in a method called by an interval timer, which holds the maximum value for each interval.  The "`$scope.totalCount()`" method, retrieves the total value associated with the cell.

Comment: You dont need canvas to make lines. It can be done simply with HTML+CSS. absolutely bottom positioned div with fixed 1px height and 0-100% width do the same job..

Comment: If you post that as an answer with some elaboration, I'll mark it as the answer.  The width should be obtained from a javascript expression, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, simple example:

```js
function getColor(value){
    //value from 0 to 1
    var hue=((1-value)*120).toString(10);
    return "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)";
}

// this part will handle angularjs simply in template like
// <div class="bar" style="width: {{ n*100 }}%;background-color: {{ getColor(n) }}%;>
let bars = document.querySelectorAll('.cell-bar');

for (let i=0;i<bars.length;i++) {
  let n = Number(bars[i].parentNode.textContent);
  bars[i].style.backgroundColor = getColor(n);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.cell-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.cell-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td><div class="cell-content">0.47<div class="cell-bar" style="width: 47%;"></div></div></td>
  <td><div class="cell-content">0.75<div class="cell-bar" style="width: 75%;"></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="cell-content">0.31<div class="cell-bar" style="width: 31%;"></div></div></td>
  <td><div class="cell-content">1<div class="cell-bar" style="width: 100%;"></div></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually, the cell background color is used for something else. The length of the line is what I'm trying to vary.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr dont know how your angularjs controller looks like so it is hard to tell exactly what to do. To get width of bar, you must know possible range (min, max), convert cell value to percentage and use it in template like n in my js comment.